# Ruby on Rails application can not find stylesheets and javascript in production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, assets

I deploy a `Ruby on Rails` application in `ubuntu` with `passenger` and `nginx`, but it cannot find the `css` and `js` files in my application.

Here is the error message:

```
open() "/var/nginx/blog/public/stylesheets/application.css" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

In fact, `/var/nginx/blog/public/stylesheets/application.css` don't exist actually, my `js` files is in `/var/nginx/blog/app/assets/javascripts/`, my `css` files is in `/var/nginx/blog/app/assets/stylesheets`

In my `nginx.conf`, I write this:

```
location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|system)/ {
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

It seems that this is the place which is wrong! But I comment this, it still cannot find `js` and `css`.
how do I config to get these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should put your assets in `public/` folder. Do you try precompile the assets?

`rake assets:precompile`

Comment: this is the standard directory structure of ruby on rails application, you mean I run rake assets:precompile in Ubuntu?

Comment: I think that Vladis answer is correct! the correct command is: `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 2):

You should to run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on remote server where you deploying.

`assets:precompile` rake task compressing and minimizing your assets for fast and reliable high-load production usage. Do not need to run this task on your development enviroment.

Would be better if you can show your deploy script. But most of deployment solutions like capistrano automaticaly doing this things right.